# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method --- from the type --- Java Bukkit Minecraft

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I know there have been plenty of other posts like this from people trying to find their problem in their static class and I have read them but to no avail. I am trying to make a minecraft bukkit plugin for bedwars and when trying to use world.--- I constantly get these errors(Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getPlayers from the type World) and cannot find where the static class is originating from. Here is my code:

```
package me.fitch.bedwars.timers;

import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import me.fitch.bedwars.main;


public class starttimer implements Listener {
    private main plugin;
    public starttimer(main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void startjoin(PlayerJoinEvent e)
    {
        Object [] players = World.getPlayers().toArray(); //error here
        if(players.length == 8)
        {
            //start countdown
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help and that I'm not just blind
Thanks :)

Edit: after instantiating `World server = new World();` I am now getting "Cannot instantiate the type World" errors, thanks for the help so far guys, hope you can help with this :)

Edit 2: so `e.getPlayer().getWorld()` works now so thanks but I'm now having issues in my main class where e is not a thing

```
package me.fitch.bedwars;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import me.fitch.bedwars.listeners.beddestroy;



public class main extends JavaPlugin {
    private main plugin;
    public main(main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
    @Override
    public void onEnable()
    {
        
        World.setSpawnLocation(Integer.parseInt( plugin.getConfig().getString("respawn_pointx")), Integer.parseInt( plugin.getConfig().getString("respawn_pointx")) + 1,Integer.parseInt( plugin.getConfig().getString("respawn_pointz")));
        new beddestroy(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: also, what is `private main plugin;` ? at first glance that seems like a compilation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want your listener in its own class `myListener.java`.

From within the listener events in that class you should be able to do everything you need to do.

I like to create a `public static Plugin` object in case you ever need to reference the specific instance of the Plugin object from any other class in your plugin.

You will register the listener like this in `Main.onEnable()`

```
package myPlugin;

import myPlugin.myListenerClass;

import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public static Plugin instance;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
    
        instance = this;

        PluginManager my_pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
        my_pm.registerEvents(new myListenerClass(), this); 
    }
}
```

Your myListenerClass.java will be setup something like the following:

```
package myPlugin;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

public class myListenerClass implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {

        System.out.println("PlayerJoinEvent was triggered!");

        int playerCount = Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers().size();

        if (playerCount == 8) {
            // start countdown
        }
    }
}
```